# MySQL slave stuck on Applying batch of row changes (read)

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-8.0, master-slave-replication

***Might be duplicate of:***

- [MySQL slave stuck on Applying batch of row changes (write)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228006/mysql-slave-stuck-on-applying-batch-of-row-changes-write)
  or
- [MySQL8.0 Replication Got Stuck "Applying batch of row changes (delete)"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265438/mysql8-0-replication-got-stuck-applying-batch-of-row-changes-delete)

I am trying to use MySQL 8.0.26 in master and slave configuration.

The master database has a very large write workload. I suspect this is due to configuration miss-match related to parallel execution of transactions.

It worked when I first configured it, but now it is stuck. It's stuck in `Applying batch of row changes (delete)`.

```
mysql> show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for source to send event
                  Master_Host: mysql-host
                  Master_User: slave
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000193
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 509776246
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000038
                Relay_Log_Pos: 938746
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000086
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 938531
              Relay_Log_Space: 136680192903
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 647694
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 6da8b175-05c9-11ec-99ed-00b771a288f6
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Applying batch of row changes (delete)
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
       Master_public_key_path:
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace:
```

---

---

Outputs of following:

- SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS: https://pastebin.com/Bxr2t641
- SHOW GLOBAL STATUS: https://pastebin.com/9j94St7C
- SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES: https://pastebin.com/9j94St7C

Answer (score 0):

Once in a while, I see replication stuck with a large `Seconds_behind_master`.  Sometimes I would see it alternating between a large value and zero.  It always went away (eventually).  And nothing seemed to be amiss in the replicated data.

I first saw this in Version 4.0 !